# linked list , the reverse function , data structure

Tags: c++

why is this code working fine :

```
  Node *prev ,*cur ,*aft;
    prev = NULL;
    cur = head;
    aft= cur->next;
    while(cur != NULL)
    {
        aft=cur->next;
        cur->next =prev;
        prev =cur;
        cur=aft;
        
    }
    head = prev;
```

and this code is not working :

```
   Node *prev ,*cur ,*aft;
    prev = NULL;
    cur = head;
    aft= cur->next;
    while(cur != NULL)
    {
        
        cur->next =prev;
        prev =cur;
        cur=aft;
        aft=cur->next;
    }
    head = prev;
```

why when i put (aft = cur->next) last in while loop , the code doesnt work?????
what is the logical error ????

Comment: Draw a linked list out on paper, and you will see why the first example works.

Comment: First what is the difference between `cu->next` and `after` please get your implementaion right and as @PaulMcKenzie mentioned Draw your linklist on paper.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  i have drawn it many times and i cannot clarify the diference???

Comment: @UmarFarooq "aft = cur->next" refer that aft pointer will move on one node , "cur->next = prev" makes the node which cur pointer on it link with the previous node , "after" refer to the node after the cur

Comment: Your question says you don't know why the first one works.  Is this true?  If you take a look at the first example -- the first line in the `while` loop`aft=cur->next;` this saves the next pointer in `aft`.  Look at the last line before the loop ends `cur=aft;` -- that makes `cur` point to that saved `aft` pointer so that the next node gets processed when the loop goes back to the top.  The first and last lines should give you a clue as to why they are there and why this works.  The second example does none of this -- there is no saving of the next element before any manipulation is done.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie okay i begin to figure it out , in the first code , in the first line in the while loop "aft = cur->next  " saves the next pointer in the aft , then what is the usage of "aft = cur->next" that is behind the while loop , why it was written twice ? One before loop and one in the loop ?

Comment: The one before the loop is not necessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ohhhhhhhh, i get it now, thank you very much , my regards to you ❤️❤️can you teach me data structure ♥️

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry for the too many questions , but if you see in the secound case , line before the while loop "aft= cur->next" thats mean that :save the next pointer in aft ,Then in while "cur -> aft " so cur pointer goes to the the address which aft pointer to , so what is the problem here ? I think they are connected now ??

Comment: By inspection (i.e. I have not tested this) the problem occurs when you reach the end of the list.

Comment: @Beta yup thats true because  when the curr is NULL  so the aft pointer is not pointing anywhere so the code blow , if you want to fix ,check before the last line in while loop "if (cur = NULL) then break the loop,. The code will run fine now

Answer (score 0):

It seems like to me you need to understand that when you define values they get changed:

```
aft=cur->next;
cur->next =prev;
prev =cur;
cur=aft;
```

In this sample you changed aft to current next first before you changed curr->next to prev.

```
        cur->next =prev;
        prev =cur;
        cur=aft;
        aft=cur->next;
```

In this example you changed the curr->next before you updated after: For a comparison try the following:

```
int five = 5;
int seven = five;
five = 7;
cout << seven;
```

Prints out 5, but

```
int five = 5;
five = 7;
int seven = five;
cout << seven;
```

Prints out 7..
See the difference??